# Topology of fiber bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, fiber-bundles

> Everything is over $\mathbb C$. Let $X\to \mathbb P^1$ be a fiber bundle with fiber some smooth projective variety $F$. If we have another such bundle $Y \to \mathbb P^1$, then, for which $p,q$ we have the Hodge number $h^{p,q}(X)=h^{p,q}(Y)$?

Apparently, the outer Hodge numbers (essentially $h^{p,0}$) are equal since they are birational equivalent. But can we expect more? Is it true that all the Hodge numbers of $X$ and $Y$ are equal? (I know this is true for projective bundles, i.e. $F\cong \mathbb P^n$, but I have no idea for general bundles. I guess it is not.)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by a fiber bundle? For instance, do you take a fiber bundle to mean that this fiber bundle is locally trivial in the Zariski topology? Or something else?

Comment: @KReiser Yes, I mean locally trivial in the Zariski topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true in general, the keyword is Grothendieck ring of varieties. I am not sure for a reference, but it's probably in the recent book by Chambert-Loir, Nicaise and Sebag about motivic integration.

There is a ring $\mathrm K_0(\mathrm{Var}/\Bbb C)$ defined as follows : take the free abelian group generated by algebraic varieties over $\Bbb C$. Define a product as $[X] \cdot [Y] = [X \times Y]$, and impose the relations $[X] = [U] + [Z]$ for any open set $U \subset X, Z = X \backslash U$.

**Theorem** : There is a unique morphism $\mathrm K_0(\mathrm{Var}/\Bbb C) \to \Bbb Z[u,v]$ that coincide with Hodge polynomials $\sum_{p,q}h^{p,q}u^pv^q$ on projective smooth varieties.

It is easy to check that if $X \to B$ is a fiber bundle in the Zariski topology with fiber $F$, then $[X] = [F] \cdot [B]$ in $K_0$. In particular, with your notation $[X] = [Y]$ in $\mathrm{K}_0(\mathrm{Var}/ \Bbb C)$ so their Hodge polynomial coincide.

Comment: In the past there has been much wailing and gnashing of teeth here on MSE about actually demonstrating that $[X]=[F]\cdot[B]$, see for instance [these counterexamples](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158424/fibrations-with-isomorphic-fibers-but-not-zariski-locally-trivial) which show that the obvious strategy of "find a Zariski open so the fibration is trivial, cut, repeat" does not work. Can you provide the proof of this statement or a reference to a source where it is proven?

Comment: @KReiser : Thanks a lot for all your comments it's really helpful as often I forget to check details. I assumed that "fiber bundles" meant locally trivial fiber bundles (for the Zariski topology). If it means "fibration with fiber $F$" not indeed my answer doesn't work (but I don't know any counter-example to the OP question). Maybe the OP can say what is meant by "fiber bundles"?

Comment: @KReiser : I realize now that this notion of "fiber bundles" in the Zariski topology is too strong and probably not so interesting, for example the monodromy should be trivial. So indeed it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Oh boy! I had read "fibration" instead of fiber bundle. If the OP does mean a Zariski-locally trivial fiber bundle, the strategy in your answer is correct as you say and I'm sorry to have troubled you as a result of my hasty reading. (The secret about these counterexamples is that I got hit with this issue on a separate post a few years ago - you can get around the issue by using the fact that $K_0$ is invariant under passing  from schemes/C to algebraic spaces, where the stated strategy actually works. So your post is on the whole correct, up to possibly one argument being adjusted.)

Comment: @KReiser : Wonderful !! Do you know a reference about this invariance of $K_0$ ?

Comment: Section 2 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.5404.pdf) contains the claim, but not a proof. I suppose it falls in to the annoying category of "known to experts" - you could always email the author to request a more thorough accounting.

Comment: @KReiser : Reading the paper you linked, I found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.3143.pdf) where it is stated that there exists a $G$-torsor $X \to B$ so that $[X] \neq [G] \cdot [B]$. Isn't a contradiction ?

Comment: It's not clear to me right now, sorry. My first guess would be something to do with $PSL$ not being an algebraic group? Or maybe the fibrations aren't etale-locally trivial - if you have this, then you can decompose the base in to sets locally closed in the etale topology so that the the fibration is an honest product, then stitch everything back together using the obvious relations. I'll think about it and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @KReiser : I think there is an alternative proof without the Grothendieck ring. By Deligne, the Leray spectral sequence associated to $f : X \to B$ degenerates if $f$ is projective. This isomorphism should respect the Hodge structure (probably overkilled but here is a [reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0301140) ).

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Thank you for the answer! And your discussion is also very helpful.